# Hazelcast 3.7.4 fails to reinitialize map

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Hazelcast can't reinit map from MapLoader in a case when first attempt fails.
MapLoader loads data from Database.

Test case:

1. Start Server Member
2. Start Client Member
3. Break connection to Database
4. Try to get data from Hazelcast Map (initiates Lazy Loading from MapLoader)
   Observe exception.
5. Restore connection to DB
6. Repeat step 4. Exception from step 4 repeats.

As a result Hazelcast goes to state when Map can't be initialized at all without restart.

Did you met such behaviour?

Recommend, please, workaround or solution?

**UPDATE:**

Such behaviour is reproduced if call map.keySet() from client member side.

Comment: Could you provide the stacktrace describing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long investigation cause of problem was not found, but Hazelcast map restores if after fail initialization invoke map.size().
It is quite strange but it works.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to get/put/remove data over a map, Hazelcast only calls related `MapStore` and `MapLoader` methods. There is no specific method call for the initialization of the your DB connections (Hazelcast provides a `MapLoaderLifecycleSupport` interface in order to initialize the MapLoader implementation, but its `init()` method is again only called when the map is first used on the Hazelcast instance, not each time you perform map operations).

Thus; you need to handle database connectivity issues on your own, in your `MapStore` implementation. For instance; when you are trying to put/read/remove data to/from your DB in the implementation, you need to check for the connection and re-establish if it doesn't exist.

Comment: You are right that I need to manage connection by myself but Hazelcast doesn't invoke MapLoader if first initialization fails. So, if you even re-esteblished connection Hazelcast will not call MapLoader ever and Map will stay at failed state and will return previous exception.